Intersection of Simple Closed Curves with finite point
Suppose $C_1$ and $C_2$ are two Rectifiable curve simple closed Curves, $C_1 \cap C_2$ ={$x_1,x_2,...,x_n$}, Are the intersection of the interiors of two curves be expressed as the union of the interiors of a finite number of simple closed curves?
This problem is arose because I try to understand the proof of Generalized Cauchy's Integral formula.
